# Sorting Python Inside A Lists

Tags: python

```
data = []

while True:
    print(url)
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
    links = soup.select_one('li.page-item.nb.active')
    
    for links in soup.find_all("h6", {"class": "text-primary title"}):
        sublink = links.find("a").get("href")
        new_link = "LINK" + sublink
        response2 = requests.get(new_link)
        soup2 = BeautifulSoup(response2.content, 'html.parser')
        
        # print('-------------------')
        heading = soup2.find('h1').text
        print(heading)

        table = soup2.find_all('tbody')[0]
        for i in table.find_all('td', class_='title'):
            movies = i.find('a', class_="text-primary")
            for movie in movies:
                data.append((heading,movie))
                
        df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
        df.to_csv('list.csv', index=False, encoding='utf-8')

    next_page = soup.select_one('li.page-item.next>a')
    if next_page:
        next_url = next_page.get('href')
        url = urljoin(url, next_url)
    else:
        break
```

Hello Guys! How can i sort the result on CSV like this one, i try my best on sorting but as a beginner its very hard to me to do it.........................

EXAMPLE

```
Column1 | Column2  
James | Movie1, Movie2, Movie3
Peter | Movie1, Movie2, Movie3
```

Want i am getting right now is

`Column1 | Column2`
`James, movie 1`
`James, movie 2`
`James, movie 3`

Comment: Where is the variable `data` defined?

Comment: Above on while true i will update the code

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Good places to start are the [tour] and [ask]. Please edit your code to make it a [mre].

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and [mre]. If the question is about how to change the DataFrame, then **do not show** code to read a webpage and parse the data. Just make sure it is clear **exactly what the DataFrame contains, before** the desired change; and show **what the result should be**, not just what you get now. Also: is part of the code here supposed to be doing the sorting? I don't see anything that tries to do anything like sorting. We can only answer questions about the code *that is actually shown to us*.

Comment: @Karl Knechtel hi bro thanks for commenting and in the informations above. i will add some code and update it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of iterating through movies, use `", ".join(movies)`

```
while True:
    print(url)
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
    links = soup.select_one('li.page-item.nb.active')
    
    for links in soup.find_all("h6", {"class": "text-primary title"}):
        sublink = links.find("a").get("href")
        new_link = "LINK" + sublink
        response2 = requests.get(new_link)
        soup2 = BeautifulSoup(response2.content, 'html.parser')
        
        # print('-------------------')
        heading = soup2.find('h1').text
        print(heading)

        table = soup2.find_all('tbody')[0]
        movies = []
        for i in table.find_all('td', class_='title'):
            movies +=  i.find('a', class_="text-primary")
        data.append((heading, ", ".join(movies)))
                
        df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
        df.to_csv('list.csv', index=False, encoding='utf-8')

    next_page = soup.select_one('li.page-item.next>a')
    if next_page:
        next_url = next_page.get('href')
        url = urljoin(url, next_url)
    else:
        break
```

Comment: Hi, Bro im getting the same result

Comment: Well, i didn't see the data so i couldn't reproduce the example. I did a modification, try now.

Comment: WOW !!!!! Thank you so much bro i will try to learn this i got this thank you and now working